# How do I open a binary matrix and convert it into a 2D array or a dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a binary matrix in a txt file that looks as follows:

```
0011011000
1011011000
0011011000
0011011010
1011011000
1011011000
0011011000
1011011000
0100100101
1011011000
```

I want to make this into a 2D array or a dataframe where there is one number per column and the rows are as shown. I've tried using numpy and pandas, but the output has only one column that contains the whole number. I want to be able to call an entire column as a number.

One of the codes I've tried is:

```
with open("a1data1.txt") as myfile:
    dat1=myfile.read().split('\n')
dat1=pd.DataFrame(dat1)
```

Comment: Hmmm, so read_fwf does not work? Or there was some problem?

Comment: read_fwf also works, but it requires me to know the width, which I don't necessarily know before opening the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you read your txt, you can using following code fix it

```
pd.DataFrame(df[0].apply(list).values.tolist())
Out[846]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0
4  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
5  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
6  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
7  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
8  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1
9  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: @S.Quon if you like , those answer, you can eighth upvote and accept it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) with parameter `widths`:

```
df = pd.read_fwf("a1data1.txt", header=None, widths=[1]*10)

print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0
4  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
5  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
6  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
7  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
8  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1
9  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
```